# Mean value of $\Omega(n)$ is $\log\log n$

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory

This question is from my number theory assignment and I was unable to solve it. I have been following Dekonick and Luca.

> Let $\Omega(n)$ be the number of prime divisors of n, counted with multiplicity ie the number of prime powers dividing n, for instance $\Omega(12) = 3$. Show that mean value of $\Omega(n)$ is $\log\log n$: $\frac{1}{N}\sum_{n\leq N} \Omega(n) = \log\log N+O(1)$.

Attempt: I thought of using Abel's Identity : $\sum_{n\leq N} f(n) = f(N)[N]- \int_{1}^x [t] f'(t)\,dt$.

Here $f(n) = f(p_1^{x_1} \cdots p_r^{x_r}) = x_1 + \dots + x_r$

So, I got $\sum_{n\leq N} f(n) = (x_1 + \dots + x_r)[N]- \int_{1}^{x} [t] (x_1+\dots+x_r) \log t\,dt$. Dividing by $N$, $((x_1 + \dots + x_r)[N])/N =O(1)$, and the other term after simplifying I got as $$(x_1+\dots+x_r)(\log N -1-(N\log N)/2+N/4+1/N(3/4))$$ which is not equal to what has to be proved.

So, please help.

Comment: partial summation is for removing continuous functions, not for removing the sequence.  here you (i think) just need to write in the explicit definition of $\Omega $.  for example, if the question was about $\omega $ (which is a very similar function) then your sum would be $\sum _{n\leq x}\sum _{p|n}1$ which you can then rearrange and get a result.

Answer (score 2):

Using a collection of useful results (left as a home exercise to polish the details) ... let's note by:
$$d(n,k)=\left\{\begin{matrix}
1, & k\mid n \\ 
0, & k \nmid n 
\end{matrix}\right.$$
[Then](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_omega_function#Properties_and_relations), where $p_i$ is the $i$-th prime:
$$\Omega(n)=\sum\limits_{p^\alpha \mid n}1=
\sum\limits_{i=1}\sum\limits_{\alpha=1}d(n, p_i^\alpha)$$
[And](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Exchange_of_Order_of_Summation)
$$\sum\limits_{n=1}^N\Omega(n)=
\sum\limits_{n=1}^N \left(\sum\limits_{i=1}\sum\limits_{\alpha=1}d(n, p_i^\alpha)\right)=
\sum\limits_{i=1} \left(\sum\limits_{n=1}^N\sum\limits_{\alpha=1}d(n, p_i^\alpha)\right)=\\
\sum\limits_{i=1} \left(\sum\limits_{\alpha=1}\sum\limits_{n=1}^N d(n, p_i^\alpha)\right)=
\sum\limits_{i=1} \left(\sum\limits_{\alpha=1}\left\lfloor \frac{N}{p_i^{\alpha}} \right\rfloor\right)=...$$
[which](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre%27s_formula) is
$$...=\sum\limits_{i=1} \nu_{p_i}(N!)=...$$
[in fact](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3899131/there-exist-infinitely-many-prime-numbers-p%E2%89%A52-and-there-exist-positive-integer/3899243#3899243)
$$...=\sum\limits_{i=1}^{\pi(N)} \nu_{p_i}(N!)$$
[Given](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1326378/asymptotic-solution-for-p-adic-order-of-n-for-all-primes)
$$\frac{n}{p-1}-\log_2(n+1)<\frac{n}{p-1}-\log_p(n+1)\le\nu_p(n!)\le\frac{n}{p-1}$$
we have
$$\sum\limits_{p\leq N}\frac{1}{p-1} - \frac{\pi(N)\log_2(N+1)}{N}<\frac{\sum\limits_{i=1}^{\pi(N)} \nu_{p_i}(N!)}{N}<\sum\limits_{p\leq N}\frac{1}{p-1}$$
Or
$$\sum\limits_{p\leq N}\frac{1}{p} - \frac{\pi(N)\log_2(N+1)}{N}<\frac{\sum\limits_{i=1}^{\pi(N)} \nu_{p_i}(N!)}{N}<\sum\limits_{p\leq N}\frac{1}{p} + \sum\limits_{p\leq N}\frac{1}{p(p-1)}$$

The final result follows from the [Prime Number Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem) and the [summation of the reciprocals of the primes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence_of_the_sum_of_the_reciprocals_of_the_primes).

Comment: Prime number theorem is not needed to deduce this asymptotic formula. See my answer

Comment: @TravorLZH I need it in my answer, to deal with $\frac{\pi(N)\log_2(N+1)}{N}$ in LHS.

Comment: You can use the weaker Chebyshev upper bound

Comment: @TravorLZH yep, that will work as well.

Comment: @rtybase Can you please tell how you wrote $\sum_{i=1} v_{p_i}(N!)= \sum_{i=1}^{\pi(N)} v_{p_i}(N!)$? I was not able to deduce them using the link given. Kindly elaborate on it.

Comment: @evan, that is because $$p_{\pi (N)} \leq N < p_{\pi (N)+1}$$ and for any $p> N$ ($p$-prime) we have $\nu_p(N!)=0$.

Answer (score 2):

By definition, we know

\begin{aligned}
0\le\sum_{n\le N}[\Omega(n)-\omega(n)]
&=\sum_{n\le N}\sum_{p^a\|n,a>1}a\le\sum_{a\ge2}a\sum_{p\le N}\sum_{\substack{n\le N\\p^a|n}}1 \\
&\le\sum_{a\ge2}a\sum_{p\le N}{N\over p^a}\le N\sum_{p\le N}\sum_{a\ge2}{a\over p^a}
\end{aligned}

To evaluate the rightmost sum, we recall the properties of geometric series. That is, for $|z|<1$ there is

$$
{1\over1-z}=1+z+\sum_{r\ge2}z^r
$$

Differentiating on both side, we have

$$
{1\over(1-z)^2}=1+\sum_{r\ge2}rz^{r-1}
$$

Multiplying $z$ on both side gives

$$
\sum_{r\ge2}rz^r={z-z(z^2-2z+1)\over(1-z)^2}={z^2(2-z)\over(1-z)^2}
$$

This indicates that

$$
\sum_{p\le N}\sum_{a\ge2}{a\over p^a}=\sum_{p\le N}{p^{-2}(2-p^{-1})\over(1-p^{-1})^2}\le\sum_{p\le N}{2\over(p-1)^2}
$$

Since the right most sum is convergent, we conclude

$$
\sum_{n\le N}[\Omega(n)-\omega(n)]=\mathcal O(N)
$$

which indicates that

$$
\sum_{n\le N}\Omega(n)=\sum_{n\le N}\omega(n)+\mathcal O(N)\tag1
$$

which converts our problem into a much more convenient one:

\begin{aligned}
\sum_{n\le N}\omega(n)
&=\sum_{n\le N}\sum_{p|n}1=\sum_{p\le N}\sum_{\substack{n\le N\\p|n}}1 \\
&=\sum_{p\le N}\left\lfloor\frac Np\right\rfloor=N\sum_{p\le N}\frac1p+\mathcal O(N)
\end{aligned}

To continue, we summon Mertens' formula (a superior version is presented as Theorem 427 in Hardy & Wright):

$$
\sum_{p\le N}\frac1p=\log\log N+\mathcal O(1)
$$

so that

$$
\sum_{n\le N}\omega(n)=N\log\log N+\mathcal O(N)\tag2
$$

Combining (1) and (2) gives the desired result.

Comment: It should be $O(n)$, not $\mathcal{O}(n)$. Customarily, $\mathcal{O}$ stands for the sheaf of holomorphic functions, which deeply studied by Oka.

Comment: @Landau I've seen many uses of $\mathcal O$ in literature, and I don't think the use of $\mathcal O$ here would lead to ambiguity.

Comment: @TravorLZH I am not able to understand 1st line of your answer. Can you please tell how did you wrote :$0\leq sum_{n\leq N} [|Omega(n)- \omega(n)|] \leq \sum_{n\leq N} \sum_{p^a |n , a >1 a$ . Kindly elaborate.

Comment: $\Omega(n)=\sum_{p^a\|n}a$ and $\omega(n)=\sum_{p|n}1$, so that's why the difference looks like what's stated.

Comment: @TravorLZH What is the meaning of the symbol $p^a$  2 times divide n ? Can u please tell?

Comment: The symbol means that $p^a$ divides $n$ and $p^{a+1}$ does not.

Comment: @TravorLZH I think $\Omega (n) $ should be equal to $\sum_{p^a || n} 1$ not the one you wrote in your previous comment. What do you think?

Comment: Normally, we only sum each $p$ once, so to ensure $\Omega(n)$ counts the $p$ with multiplicities we have to make sure the summand is $a$ when we sum over each $p^a\|n$.